# Polo Classic: Idle Issues

Tags: engine, vw, idle, polo

There's a while that I'm trying to repair a Brazilian [Polo Classic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Polo_Classic) 1999 (based on the European [VW Polo MK3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Polo_Mk3)) with idling running at low RPM. Long story short:

- When the engine is cold, the idle stays at ≈600RPM while the correct should be 900~1000RPM.
  (Watch the video: [idling with AC off](https://streamable.com/0ow4ig))
- If you turn on the AC, then the idle drops to ≈500RPM almost killing the engine.
  (Watch the video: [idling with AC on](https://streamable.com/d4khxo))
- When the engine gets warmer, this situation improves a little bit but it is still noticeable and unpleasant.
- I have already went to several workshops, which checked the usual stuff (ex: false air intakes, scanner fault readings, stepper motor, ECU reset ...). However, unfortunately, none could definitely solve the issue.

#### Question

Any recommendation about how to solve this low RPM idling issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!